# How to populate a form field based on the choice done on a previous form field

Tags: django

models.py

```
title_choices=(('Software Engineer Trainee',"Software Engineer Trainee"),
('Senior Software Engineer ',"Senior Software Engineer"))
op_title = models.CharField(max_length=768, blank=True,choices=title_choices,default="Software Engineer Trainee")
op_skill_required = models.CharField(max_length=3072, blank=True)
op_skill_preferred = models.CharField(max_length=3072, blank=True)
```

im using form.as_table to render the form in order to display in my web page. so when i click on one of the title_choices, based on the choice i want to populate the skill_preferred and skill_required field of my form... Is der a way to do it???

Answer (score 0):

You need a client side solution for this; one that can query your server for information when the user selects a choice.

Since this is a common task, there are numerous third-party modules available that do this.  [`django-ajax-selects`](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) is one of them, and the [`dajax` project](http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/) provides such integrations for django.

Comment: if im using forms can ajax be used. im using form.as_table to display the form.